# How can I find the width of spaces between two fields/comboboxes in an hbox layout for Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, whitespace, spacing

For Ext JS, I have a datefield next to a combobox, and a space has automatically been inserted between. To the right of the combobox is a checkbox with another space in between.

I used the following to determine the space in between:

```
var space1 = space1 = comboboxRef.el.getLeft() - datefieldRef.el.getRight(),
space2 = chkBoxRef.el.getLeft() - comboboxRef.el.getRight();
```

How can I find **space1** and **space2** using a different method?

More specifically, how do I find the set width of the space without having to compare the right and left of the form field?

Comment: I don't think you can find that without manually calculating because it was all calculated by the framework `Layout`. Why do you need to find out the amount of space you have between fields? Maybe there is some other way to get that part done.

Comment: I am trying to get the number of pixels in one "row" of elements. I need to include the spaces in between elements.

Comment: If you need the total number of pixels wouldn't it be just a matter of multiplying the row width by it's height? Not sure why the empty spaces need to be calculated. Can you maybe write a fiddle with what you are trying to achieve in general?

Comment: In general checking left and right etc now causes issues with browser performance especially in chrome.  Hopefully your doing these things in an area of the page that isn't scrollable.  See "Forced Reflow in Chrome"

Comment: My mistake in my explanation; essentially, I am trying to add the widths of all the elements that are side by side.